# No labels with R micromap package on Mac

Tags: r, macos, data-visualization

I had no trouble running the following micromap demo code on Windows, but on my Mac, the labels don't print.

I've attached the graphic (without labels) that appears in the plot window after running this code:

```
library (micromap)
data("USstates")
statePolys <- create_map_table(USstates, 'ST')
data("edPov")

# basic figure 1
mmplot(stat.data=edPov,
       map.data=statePolys,
       panel.types=c('labels', 'dot', 'dot','map'),
       panel.data=list('state','pov','ed', NA),
       ord.by='pov',
       grouping=5, median.row=TRUE,
       map.link=c('StateAb','ID'))
```

[image: micromap plot on Mac without labels]

I get the following warning:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
  no font could be found for family "NA"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apparently there's no font set. Did you try `par(family = 'Arial')` (or some font)?

Comment: That's not it. I don't have trouble with fonts in other plots... also the error would be "no font could be found for family 'Arial'" in that case. The (required) NA is causing the problem but I don't know why/how.

Comment: Oh yikes, that jacks around Quartz something fierce. It looks like the problem is buried deeper in how it calls `grid` to arrange its panels, but I'm not sure it's user-fixable. Report a bug?

Comment: We are currently working on an update to the micromap package and you could try the development version of the package available on GitHub (https://github.com/USEPA/R-micromap-package-development/tree/development). If the problem persists with use of the development version can put in a pull request - we've had issues with fonts and would like to fix if we can.

Comment: you may be interested in this geojson https://github.com/hrbrmstr/albersusa/blob/master/inst/extdata/composite_us_states.geojson.gz. it's already elided the US AK & HI and can be projected with `coord_map('albers')` (vs have it be an unprojected map)

Comment: Thanks @mweber, still having the problem with the dev version. I'll submit a pull request.